# Can't evaluate field <field> in type string

Tags: go, go-templates

I'm used `text/template` in golang package to parse text with environment in json string.

Example: https://play.golang.org/p/uARnrOyG4Th

But I have an error: `2009/11/10 23:00:00 Execute: template: Person template:1:19: executing "Person template" at <.id>: can't evaluate field id in type string`

Please help me with problem. I couldn't find the error based on the library's documents.

Comment: person is a string in your code, not a struct. If you JSON unmarshal it into a struct value, then the template code can use reflection to access the fields like id etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

template can't directly apply to string, you should create a struct then unmarshal your JSON string to the struct instance. [try the code](https://play.golang.org/p/45h106YG55M)

Answer (score -1):

```golang
person := map[string]string{"id": "12345", "token": "NSJACSCS"}
```

output:

```
momo://pay?appid=12345&token=NSJACSCS
Program exited.
```